# Performed a smoothing function on a matrix, but now only matching indices give values

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix 1000x1000x50 and I performed a function on each vector along the third dimension in a loop (1,000,000 vectors, 50 elements long). When I try to view any specific element where m=n, i.e. (1000,1000,40) , a nonzero value is displayed. However, when I try to view an element where m =/= n, i.e. (1000,1001,40), only a 0 is returned. I know that (1001,1001,40) has a nonzero value, and I know that the original matrix had a nonzero element at (1000,1001,40).

Here's the loop I used:

```
mymatrix_new = zeros(size(mymatrix));
for i=1:length(mymatrix)
    mymatrix_new(i,i,:) = wdenoise(squeeze(mymatrix(i,i,:)));
end
```

For the values that DO display, the result is what I expected- a smoothed signal. I just don't understand why certain elements that are nonzero are displaying as zero when the m and n indices are't identical.

Comment: Those dimensions don't match. Why are you accessing 1001 in a dimension sized 1000?

Comment: I picked a bad arbitrary number for the example, but you're obviously correct that there can't be a 1001th element in a 1000 element array :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating and updating only the cells that have m == n. This happens because you use a single for loop. All other values are not visited and are never updated, this is why they remain zero.

If you look at your foor loop:

```
for i=1:length(mymatrix)
```

In the first iteration i = 1 and it will update:

```
mymatrix_new(1,1,:) = wdenoise(squeeze(mymatrix(1,1,:)));
```

In the second iteration i = 2 and it will update:

```
mymatrix_new(2,2,:) = wdenoise(squeeze(mymatrix(2,2,:)));
```

As you can see, you never update mymatrix_new(1, 2) or any cell other than the ones that have m == n == i

You need to use two nested for loops, such that you update all combinations of `i` and `j`

```
mymatrix_new = zeros(size(mymatrix));
for i=1:length(mymatrix)
    for j=1:length(mymatrix) % Here it assumes the matrix is a square
        mymatrix_new(i,j,:) = wdenoise(squeeze(mymatrix(i,j,:)));
    end
end
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, this is so obvious now that you say it. I'll try not to feel stupid and just feel happy I won't ever make this mistake again! Thanks so much for your help.